# Raspberry pi: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java, jframe, raspberry-pi

I just got a Raspberry Pi B+ and I am planing to write some java programs which must include GUI. I managed to connect Netbeans to the board's java path but when I try to run my HelloWorld frame I get a headless error. Basically I want to code on my laptop, deploy the code to the board and test on board's own monitor. Is that posible?

Here is the little piece of code just in case it's relevant.

```
package raspi;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Raspi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
        JLabel l = new JLabel("test1");
        f.add(l);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to start up the X server and set the DISPLAY environment variable to point to the local machine.  Although your goal is to support a program you are writing, this would probably be better handled at unix.stackexchange.com or raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the wrong place but could you go in a little more detail please? Do I need to run commands inside the code or just do a set up once and Im good to go forever?